# Problema con return en AJAX PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema al usar AJAX.

He creado una función para mandar a llamar una función dentro de una clase PHP mediante AJAX y al momento de mandar a llamar la función devuelvo respuesta con un return.

Está es mi funcion de AJAX, en donde la clase php identifica 'cmd' y lo interpreta como función.

```
function nk_route_get(ModuleUrl, Data = {}, Alert = {}) {

    if (Data['cmd']) {

        $.ajax({
            data: Data,
            url: ModuleUrl,
            type: 'get',
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (response) {


                if (response == 1) {
                    $(".alert").addClass("hidden");
                    $('#alert-success').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#alert-success-text').html("<i class=\"fa fa-check fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;" + Alert['success']);
                    $("input").css({"border-color": "#ced4da"});
                } else if (response == 2) {
                    $('#alert-danger').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#alert-danger-text').html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;Ha ocurrido un error, consulte con el administrador.<br>");
                } else {
                    $('#alert-danger').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#alert-danger-text').html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;" + response);
                    // $("#Alert").html(response);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    else {

        console.warn("No se han mandado los parametros solicitados.")

    }

}
```

Esto es lo que coloco en mi función PHP en donde llamo una función que regresa un return.

```
 $html = nk_forms::html("ul",["class"=>'list-group list-group-flush'],nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],'asjjhd'));


 $Scripts = "$('#Modal-Body').html('{$html}');";

 echo "<script>{$Scripts}</script>";;
```

Y esta es la función que devuelve un return.

```
static function html($Tag,$Attr,$Html){

        $HtmlAttr = "";

        if (!$Tag || !$Attr || !$Html){
            return false;
        }

        if (is_array($Attr)){

            foreach ($Attr as $id => $value ){
                $HtmlAttr .= $id . " = '" . "{$value}'";
            }

        }

        $HtmlTag = "<{$Tag} {$HtmlAttr} >{$Html}</{$Tag}>";

        return $HtmlTag;

    }
```

El problema de esto es que el return corta la respuesta de AJAX.

Comment: Desconozco el framework que estás usando, pero, ¿no puedes asignar un callback en lugar de usar return?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `PHP` usas en el servidor? La sintaxis corta para el array no es compatible con todas las versiones de `PHP`es posible que esté dando error

Comment: @gugadev No es un framework, estoy llamando a una funcion estatic que me devuelve un return.

Comment: Entonces no creo tengas problema en usar un callback y dentro de éste un echo.

Comment: Hola @ErnestoRM estoy utilizando la versión 7.2.

Comment: Pues por ahí no puede venir el problema

Comment: Acabo de replicar tu ejemplo en mi servidor local y ha funcionado sin problemas, quizá el problema no sea el que estás planteando, no sé ¿cómo haces la llamada a la función `nk_route_get(ModuleUrl, Data = {}, Alert = {})`?

Comment: Hola Ernesto el problema es que el echo hace un script que abre un modal con el cual se incrusta el html recibido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no soy un experto en php, pero noto que tu función html está generando html no válido. Cuando se establece un atributo para una etiqueta html se debe usar comillas dobles y no simples como lo haces tu en esta parte del ciclo:

```
if (is_array($Attr)){
   foreach ($Attr as $id => $value ){
       $HtmlAttr .= $id . " = '" . "{$value}'";
   }
}
```

Dicho esto el objetivo es generar una etiqueta como por ejemplo:

```
<div class="clase-x"></div>
```

Pero tu código está generando el html incluso con algunas separaciones indeseadas, te pongo una aproximación de lo que está generando tu funcion:

```
<div class = 'clase-x' ></div>
```

Te dejo mi código de prueba basado en el tuyo para que lo observes, para aclarar estoy escapando las comillas dobles de esa forma, si en php existe una mejor forma ya pueden comentarlo.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="Modal-Body"></div>
<?php
     function html($Tag,$Attr,$Html){
     $HtmlAttr = "";
     if (!$Tag || !$Attr || !$Html){
         return false;
     }
    if (is_array($Attr)){
        foreach ($Attr as $id => $value ){
            //esta linea es diferente a la tuya
            $HtmlAttr .= $id."=\"{$value}\"";
        }
    }
    //esta linea es diferente a la tuya
    $HtmlTag = "<{$Tag} {$HtmlAttr}>{$Html}</{$Tag}>";
    return $HtmlTag;
 }

//esta linea es una adaptación de la tuya
$html = html("ul",["class"=>'list-group list-group-flush'],html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],'asjjhd'));
$Scripts = "$('#Modal-Body').html('{$html}');";

echo "<script>{$Scripts}</script>";
?>
```

Todo este código lo he puesto en un solo archivo php así que debería funcionar así como está.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, una disculpa exactamente ese fue mi error, agradezco la atención.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo, te falta imprimir la variable `$html`:

```
$html = nk_forms::html("ul",["class"=>'list-group list-group-flush'],nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],'asjjhd'));
echo $html;
```

Comment: Claro, al final de la función tengo el echo que imprime el resultando, el problema es que el return de la funcion 'nk_forms::html' no me permite imprimir , corta y lo interpreta como un echo.

Comment: Si mandas a llamar solamente la función donde está la variable $html, ¿qué te devuelve?

Comment: Lo hace correctamente, lo que hace la función es crear un cuerpo html y evitar escribir directamente en una cadena de texto.

Answer (score 0):

desconozco el framework que esta utilizando pero en la parte de ajax solo enviar la petición y no los datos que tiene la función, mi respuesta no es 100% segurar ya que se llama la clase y segundo la funcion

```
function nk_route_get(ModuleUrl,Data,Alert) {

         $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: 'html/'+ModuleUrl+'/'+Data+'/'+Alert,
          //data: $("#myForm").serialize(), 
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (response) { 
            alert(response);
            /*
           if (response == 1) {
                    $(".alert").addClass("hidden");
                    $('#alert-success').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#alert-success-text').html("<i class=\"fa fa-check fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;" + Alert['success']);
                    $("input").css({"border-color": "#ced4da"});
                } else if (response == 2) {
                    $('#alert-danger').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#alert-danger-text').html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;Ha ocurrido un error, consulte con el administrador.<br>");
                } else {
                    $('#alert-danger').removeClass('hidden')
                    $('#alert-danger-text').html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x\"></i>&nbsp;" + response);
                    // $("#Alert").html(response);
                }
            */

            //  show_lista_asistencias(id);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                // Displaying if there are any errors
                 // $('#result').html(error);
              alert('no se pudo add los datos');
            }
        });
}
```

y en la parte de back-font coloque el siguiente codigo:

```
  <?php 

static function html($Tag,$Attr,$Html){

        $HtmlAttr = "";

        /*
        */
        if (!$Tag || !$Attr || !$Html){
            return false;
        }

        if (is_array($Attr)){

            foreach ($Attr as $id => $value ){
                $HtmlAttr .= $id . " = '" . "{$value}'";
            }

        }

        $HtmlTag = "<{$Tag} {$HtmlAttr} >{$Html}</{$Tag}>";

        echo json_encode($HtmlTag);


    }

?>
```

Comment: Al añadir un echo, remplazas la respuesta de la función que la mando a llamar perdiéndose por completo la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Así es como quedó mi codigo:

```
 //AD HTML to Modal
        $html = nk_forms::html("ul",["class"=>'list-group list-group-flush'],
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],'Fecha Solicitud:&nbsp;' ).date("d/m/Y", strtotime($CardInfo["DocDate"]))).
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],'Nombre:&nbsp;'). $CardInfo["CardName"]).
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],'Clabe:&nbsp;').$CardInfo["CardClabe"]).
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],'Email:&nbsp;'). $CardInfo["CardEmail"]).
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],'Banco:&nbsp;'). $CardInfo["CardBankName"]).
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],'Clave de Banco:&nbsp;'). $CardInfo["CardBankCode"]).
           nk_forms::html("li",['class'=>'list-group-item'],nk_forms::html("strong",[],
               nk_forms::html("a",['class'=>'pull-left','href'=>"../{$FileInfo['FilePath']}{$FileInfo['FileName']}","download"=>"{$CardInfo['CardRequestId']}{$CardInfo['CardId']}"],
                   nk_forms::html("img",['class'=>'grow',"style"=>'max-height:150px;','src'=>"../{$FileInfo['FilePath']}{$FileInfo['FileName']}"]," ")

               ),""))
        );

        $footer = nk_forms::html("button",['type'=>"button","class"=>"btn btn-danger"],"Rechazar").
            nk_forms::html("button",['type'=>"button","class"=>"btn btn-success pull-right"],"Aceptar");

        //TODO Add JS AJAX to change status to 4

        $JS[] = nk_forms::setHTML("Modal-Basic-Body", $html);
        $JS[] = nk_forms::setHTML("Modal-Basic-Footer", $footer);
        //$JS[] = '$("#DownloadFile").on("click",function () { nk_route_post("../../../includes/download_file.php",{"FileId":$("#FileId").val()});});';
        render::modal("<i class=\"fa fa-clipboard\"></i>&nbsp;Solicitud - " . $CardInfo['CardRequestId'], $JS, false);
```

En la función quedó :

```
static function html($Tag,$Attr,$Html){

        $HtmlAttr = "";

        if (!$Tag  || !$Html){
            return false;
        }

        if (is_array($Attr) && $Attr){

            foreach ($Attr as $id => $value ){
                $HtmlAttr .= $id . " = \"" . "{$value}\"";
            }

        }

        $HtmlTag = "<{$Tag} {$HtmlAttr} >{$Html}</{$Tag}>";

        return $HtmlTag;

    }
```

Me ahorre la siguiente linea de código:

```
$html = '<ul class="list-group list-group-flush"><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Fecha Solicitud:&nbsp;</strong>' . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($CardInfo["DocDate"])) . '</li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Nombre:&nbsp;</strong>' . $CardInfo["CardName"] . '</li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Clabe:&nbsp;</strong>' . /*str_repeat('*', 14) . substr(*/
            $CardInfo["CardClabe"]/*, "14", "18")*/ . '</li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Email:&nbsp;</strong>' . $CardInfo["CardEmail"] . '</li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Banco:&nbsp;</strong>' . $CardInfo["CardBankName"] . '</li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>Clave de Banco:&nbsp;</strong>' . $CardInfo["CardBankCode"] . '</li><li  class="list-group-item " ><a  class="pull-left"  href="../'. $FileInfo['FilePath']. $FileInfo['FileName'].'" download="'.$CardInfo['CardRequestId'].'_'.$CardInfo['CardId'].'" ><img  class="grow" style=" max-height:150px; " src="../'. $FileInfo['FilePath']. $FileInfo['FileName'].'"></a></li></ul>'   ;


        $footer = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Rechazar</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Aceptar</button>';
```